# validate a where clause query in c#

Tags: c#-3.0

I was asked this question in an interview.

Write a c# program which will print out all the errors in a statement.

```
(a + b == 3 and x == y or b / c == d)
```

Allowed keywords are and/or, braces are allowed and have to match. The statement has to be logically correct. Print out all the errors.

Something like a compiler or sql analyzer.

Any idea how to go about syntax checking?

Comment: Did they mention anything of the usage of FxCop or StyleCop syntax checkers? Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Hypnos If you are not able to build a wheel, you shouldn't work for a car maker

Comment: @Eric I fail to see the significance of this anecdote, unless you mixing the terms "build" and "invent".

Answer (score 2):

You're being asked to build a parser.

The computer science theory behind compilers is extensive and complex.  To keep it simple, I recommend reading Jack Crenshaw's compiler tutorial.  It will show you in the first few chapters how to do exactly this by building a top-down recursive descent parser.  His example is almost exactly what you're trying to do.  It's in Pascal, but it's still easy enough to follow and the concept still applies.

Google for "jack crenshaw let's build a compiler", or browse to:
http://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/

Answer (score 1):

That's actually pretty complicated if you want to get it 100% right. The direction to research would have to do with the keywords "finite state automata", "regular expressions" (not to be confused with Regex) and "context-free grammars". Also there's an approach called "recursive descent parser" but you'll need to understand the above concepts first.

Answer (score 1):

Matching brackets and parenthesis is easy.

```
string expression = "(a + b + (c + d) )";

int brackets = 0;
int parenthesis = 0;
foreach(char c in expression)
{
  if(c == '(') ) parenthesis++;
  if(c == ')') ) parenthesis--;

  if(parenthesis < 0) { // ERROR!!! }
  // Same logic with brackets

}
if (parenthesis != 0) { ERROR!!! }
```

Also, I would use a similar approach with "statements mergers" ( +, -, *, / ) and "statements comparators" ( ==, !=, <, <=, ... )

For each word in your expression, only a few valid keywords can follow.

As it was mentionned before, writing parsers is a difficult task, planning every exception case right away is hardly possible. This should be the general idea instead of a definitive solution.

On a final note, it is perfectly ok to have multiple passes to scan for different things. First pass is brackts/parenthesis only, then check for something else in another loop.